# Can't get NSMutableDictionary to work (xcode)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsmutabledictionary

My Objective-C experience is not good, I would love if someone can help with this.

There are some other code around but I believe I simplified this to just the problem. What I am trying to do is to save a double (packed to NSNumber) with a key, below is my code:

.h

```
@interface MyClass : something
{
    MyMap* usemap;
}
@end

@interface MyMap : something
@property (atomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary* mmap;
@end
```

.m

```
@implementation MyMap
@class MyClass;
NSMutableDictionary* mmap = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
@end

@implementation MyClass
MyMap* usemap = [MyMap alloc];

//-void { switch() { case x:
NSString* key = @"testkey";
NSNumber* value = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:1];
NSLog(@"Saving value: %@ to key: %@",value,key);
[usemap.mmap setObject:value forKey:key];
NSNumber* get = [usemap.mmap objectForKey:key];
NSLog(@"Saved value: %@ to key: %@",get,key);
```

Now this prints:

```
Saving value: 1 to key: testkey

Saved value: (null) to key: testkey
```

What am I missing? it should have saved the double number '1'.

Comment: Your `mmap` is not initialized. The code in right under `@implementation` is meaningless, it's not executed (at least when you expect it to). Put your code to the initializer or to some methods.

Comment: I moved it to a -(void)construct, which i run just after allocating. That didn't help :/

Comment: Okey! fixed it! :D i had to use  self.mmap = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];  inside a void function called after alloc. Without self. first it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override MyClass `init` method and initialize MyMap in it `usemap = [[MyMap alloc] init]`. Then override MyMap init method and initialize mmap in it `self.mmap = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]`.

Do rest of the work in MyClass overridden `init` method. Here's a rough sketch:

.h

```
@interface MyClass : something
{
    MyMap* usemap;
}
@end

@interface MyMap : something
@property (atomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary* mmap;
@end
```

.m

```
@implementation MyMap
@class MyClass;

- (instancetype)init {
    if ((self = [super init]))
        self.mmap = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    return self;
}

@end

@implementation MyClass

- (instancetype)init {

        if ((self = [super init]))
        {
              usemap = [[MyMap alloc] init];

              NSString* key = @"testkey";
              NSNumber* value = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:1];
              NSLog(@"Saving value: %@ to key: %@",value,key);
              [usemap.mmap setObject:value forKey:key];
              NSNumber* get = [usemap.mmap objectForKey:key];
              NSLog(@"Saved value: %@ to key: %@",get,key);
       }

   return self;
}
@end
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

MyMap.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyMap : NSObject
@property (atomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary* mmap;
@end
```

MyMap.m:

```
#import "MyMap.h"

@interface MyMap ()

@end

@implementation MyMap

@end
```

ViewController.m:

```
MyMap *usemap = [[MyMap alloc] init];
usemap.mmap = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

NSString* key = @"testkey";
NSNumber* value = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:1];
NSLog(@"Saving value: %@ to key: %@",value,key);
[usemap.mmap setObject:value forKey:key];
NSNumber* get = [usemap.mmap objectForKey:key];
NSLog(@"Saved value: %@ to key: %@",get,key);
```

The result:

> 2017-01-21 20:48:59.563 TestOC[4161:50263] Saving value: 1 to key: testkey
>   2017-01-21 20:48:59.564 TestOC[4161:50263] Saved value: 1 to key: testkey

Comment: Thanks, but i can't change the structure like this, any idea why that works but mine doesn't?

Comment: @user2105624， this line `MyMap* usemap = [MyMap alloc];` did not initialize a MyMap instance, `alloc` just means allot the storage.

Comment: I am confused, everything else is working fine, i have NSMutableData* etc which works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up the internals of a object is done with an `-init` method.

```
@implementation MyMap
@class MyClass;
// NO NO NO! don't even ask what this does
// NSMutableDictionary* mmap = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

// YES: Use -init to setup the initial state of an object.
- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        // NOTE: _mmap is the instance variable for the property self.mmap.
        _mmap = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```